# Unjustified "you have pending changes, please cancel or save" message on company page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

There is a bug in Stack Overflow Careers when you edit a company page. The two sections `basic info` and `statement 2` always have the following error message in red:

> You have pending changes, please cancel or save ->

No changes / edit were made to both sections. As soon as you click on them and try to navigate away from them by clicking another section this error appears.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the edit portion of a company page
2. There is a navigation on the left that allows you to edit a certain part of the page
3. Click to edit the basic info and do not make any changes
4. Try to go to another section like section 1
5. Voila bug appears
6. Try the same with the statement 2 section
7. Voila bug again

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed. It was related to the way we were comparing the draft of a section with its original values.

Thanks for the bug report.

Comment: Did you publish because statement two still gives me issues.

Comment: Yeah, oddly enough, I wasn't able to reproduce your issue with that section, only the "basic info" section. Maybe it's related to your content, I'll have to check.

Comment: Maybe it is related to this other bug http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328027/top-of-statement-2-in-careers-entered-font-is-bold-and-so-large-i-have-no-way  I'm pretty sure it is...