# Top of statement 2 in careers entered font is bold and so large - I have no way to reformat it

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm trying to update our company page and the section titled `statement 2` is giving me grief.  At the top of it there seems to be some sort of character or formatting that just will not erase.  As soon as I move to the top of statement two it reappears.

The format controls for the body only allow for bold, italics, bullet points and indent.  There is no option to change font size or header options.  So why is this font so big at the top and why can I not remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it seems like you did have some stubborn formatting in there.

Maybe it was the result of copy & paste of some markup that our editor couldn't quite handle? In any case, I've edited that section for you to remove that formatting, and the issue is now gone.

I'll make a note to test our editor a bit more thoroughly to see if we can find the offending markup.